# How to put post date in Gatsby URL?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

All the [Gatsby starter demos](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby#gatsby-starters) have a path like `/gatsby-starter-blog/hi-folks/`

How do I set it up with `/2015-05-28/hi-folks/` or just the year with `/2015/hi-folks/`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1) Just put the blog posts in directories named like you want the url to be so in this case `/2015-05-28/hi-folks/index.md`.
2) You can programmatically set paths by exporting a function from `gatsby-node.js` called `rewritePath`. It is called for each page with filesystem data for the file the page comes from + the page's metadata. So say you want to set the date of the post in your markdown's frontmatter and have each post be a simple markdown file with paths like `/a-great-blog-post.md`

So to do what you want, add to your gatsby-node.js something like:

```
import moment from 'moment'

exports.rewritePath = (parsedFilePath, metadata) => {
  if (parsedFilePath.ext === "md") {
    return `/${moment(metadata.createdAt).format('YYYY')}/${parsedFilePath.name}/`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`rewritePath` is no longer supported in Gatsby. Here's a solution confirmed to works in Gatsby 2.3,

```
const m = moment(node.frontmatter.date)
const value = `${m.format('YYYY')}/${m.format('MM')}/${slug}`
createNodeField({ node, name: 'slug', value })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `gatsby-node.js` file I added a slug generator and a template resolver.

Inside `src/posts` I added a folder `2020` inside that folder I create folders that make slug address paths like so `my-blog-post` and inside those folders, I have an `index.md` file.

Now I have URL's that look like `http://www.example.com/2020/my-blog-post/`.

```js
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Node APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/
 */

const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

// Generates pages for the blog posts
exports.createPages = async function ({ actions, graphql }) {
    const { data } = await graphql(`
        query {
            allMarkdownRemark {
                edges {
                    node {
                        fields {
                            slug
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `);
    data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach((edge) => {
        const slug = edge.node.fields.slug;
        actions.createPage({
            path: slug,
            component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
            context: { slug: slug },
        });
    });
};

// Adds url slugs to the graph data response
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
    const { createNodeField } = actions;
    if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
        const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `posts` });
        createNodeField({
            node,
            name: `slug`,
            value: slug,
        });
    }
};
```

Inside my `src/templates/blog-post.js` file I have:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

export default function BlogPost({ data }) {
    const post = data.markdownRemark;
    const tags = (post.frontmatter.tags || []).map((tag, i) => {
        return <li key={i}>#{tag}</li>;
    });

    return (
        <Layout>
            <article className="post">
                <header>
                    <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
                    <div className="meta">
                        <time>{post.frontmatter.date}</time>
                        <ul>{tags}</ul>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <section dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
            </article>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export const query = graphql`
    query($slug: String!) {
        markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
            html
            frontmatter {
                title
                date(formatString: "DD-MMMM-YYYY")
                tags
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

My markdown files then use frontmatter data like so:

```
---
title: Post title here
date: "2020-05-25T14:23:23Z"
description: "A small intro here"
tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]
---

Main post content would be here...
```